# Mutate NSMutableDictionaly while enumerating

Tags: ios

I would like to remove a key from an NSMutableDictionary while enumerating, but if I do the app will crash because I have mutated it while enumerating it. this is the code:

```
for(id key in BluetoothDeviceDictionary) {
    UIButton* btn = [BluetoothDeviceDictionary objectForKey:key];
    MCPeerID* DevicePeer = [MCPeerID alloc];
    DevicePeer = key;
    if (DevicePeer.displayName == peerID.displayName) {
        [btn removeFromSuperview];NSLog(@"LostPeer!!!!DEL");
        CountNumberOfBluetoothDevices = CountNumberOfBluetoothDevices - 1;
        [BluetoothDeviceDictionary removeObjectForKey:key2];
    }
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the dictionary and enumerate the copy:

```
NSDictionary *enumerableDictionary = [BluetoothDeviceDictionary copy]

for (id key in enumerableDictionary) {
    // edit BluetoothDeviceDictionary, don't use enumerableDictionary
}
```

Comment: is using for(id key in [BluetoothDeviceDictionary copy]) { the same?

Comment: Similar, but it will copy on each iteration of the loop, which isn't ideal

Comment: This is indeed safer (enumerating over an immutable copy - you should have mentioned it in your answer - it's not just "a copy" but an immutable one) and mutate the mutable counterpart (original). However, that's pretty inefficient (memory and cpu-time wise) - copying a large dictionary isn't for free - and there is a way to mutate while enumerating over a mutable dictionary.  Even this trick can be improved by enumerating over BluetoothDeviceDictionary allKeys] (an immutable array) instead of [BluetoothDeviceDictionary copy].

Answer (score 4):

The number of things wrong with your posted code or the number of needed improvements is high.

1. Variable and method names should begin with lower case letters.
2. The `key` variable should have a type of `MCPeerID`, not `id`.
3. There is no reason to call `[NCPeerID alloc]`.
4. You are using `==` to compare two string values. Use `isEqual:`
5. The posted code references a non-existent variable `key2`.

Below is correct code that will do what you want:

```
NSArray *keys = [BluetoothDeviceDictionary allKeys];
for (NSUInteger k = keys.count; k > 0; k--) {
    MCPeerID *key = keys[k - 1];
    UIButton *btn = BluetoothDeviceDictionary[key];
    if ([key.displayName isEqualToString:peerID.displayName]) {
        [btn removeFromSuperview];
        NSLog(@"LostPeer!!!!DEL");
        CountNumberOfBluetoothDevices--;
        [BluetoothDeviceDictionary removeObjectForKey:key];
    }
}
```

Comment: This line gives an error  DevicePeer *key = keys[k - 1]; => use of undeclared identifier key

Comment: Sorry, typo. I just fixed the line. It should be `MCPeerID *key = keys[k - 1];`